# Incompatible shapes in keras model

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I have following keras code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam

model = Sequential([
    Dense(58, input_shape=(58,), activation='relu'),
    Dense(58, input_shape=(58,), activation='relu'),
    Dense(10,  activation='softmax'),
])

model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=10,epochs=100)
```

When I run it, it gives me following error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (10, 1) and (10, 10) are incompatible
```

I am unable to get where it is finding shape `(10,1)`. If I have 10 nodes in the last layer and a softmax, shouldnt it result in shape `(10,10)` only?

Comment: I think y_train is an array of 1D encoded variable so in this case, u can use sparse_categorical_crossentropy instead of categorical_crossentropy as loss function

Comment: Please provide full error log.